# $(\ell_p,\|\cdot\|_{\infty})$ Banach or separable

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, banach-spaces, lp-spaces, separable-spaces

Is $(\ell_p,\|\cdot\|_{\infty})$ for $1\leq p<\infty$ a Banach or separable space?

is there any fast way of proving it without checking separability or completeness with the usual way?

Comment: @Frank ,and why is that?is there any fast way of proving it without checking seperability with the usual way?

Comment: @Frank,yes and i didn't find anything

Comment: Am I missing something, or is the subspace $\ell_p\subset\ell_{\infty}$ clearly _not_ a closed subspace of $(\ell_{\infty},||\cdot||_{\infty})$?

Comment: Apologies both, misread question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the inclusions of sets
$$\ell_p\subset c_0\subset \ell_\infty,$$
where $c_0$ denotes the set of convergent sequences and the separability of $(c_0,\lVert \cdot\rVert_\infty)$ is separable we conclude that $(\ell_p,\lVert\cdot\rVert_\infty)$ is separable.

$\ell_p$ endowed with the supremum norm is not a *closed* subspace of $\ell_\infty$ because its closure *for this norm* is $c_0\neq \ell_p$.